# CakePHP beginner's question about views

Tags: php, cakephp

I have finally quit the idea of learning Zend and instead i find CakePHP and CodeIgniter to be very impressive and simple to understand rather than cramming the strange global functions and configuration of index.php. Anyways, i wanted to ask you that CakePHP even spits out Html in sort of php language like :-

```
<?= $html->css('default'); ?>
```

Do i have to necessarily use this syntax only? or can i use plain old HTML's link tag to load my stylesheet? If i have to strictly follow these rules only, then how shall i use JQuery and such things in CakePHP?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I strongly suggest that you stay away from using short PHP tags. I.e. use <?php not <? or <?=.  As far as your question, I'm not familiar w/ CakePHP.  However, I would expect that you certainly can use plain HTML in your **views**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use plain html in .ctp files. However using the helpers provided by CakePHP will make your life a lot easier.

As for using JavaScript (like jquery)

```
echo $javascript->link('scriptfile');
```

Take a look at the cake book for more info:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/206/Inserting-Well-Formatted-elements

http://book.cakephp.org/view/349/Methods

Answer (score 1):

In your view files, you can use anything that would be valid in a PHP file.

- In your mind, just think HTML and PHP at the same time:
- PHP inside `<?php ... ?>` (don't *ever* do this: `<? ... ?>` - IE will fail)
- JS inside `<script type=....> ... </script>`
- HTML inside: ...well, not inside anything.
- You can include inline CSS or CSS files with HTML or via helper.
- Even PHP includes can be used.

Using the css and javascript and html image helpers, if the path you specify does not include a '/' at the first char, CakePHP will look in webroot/css (or webroot/js or webroot/img). If the first char of the path is a '/' then you can specify your own location, e.g.

- `echo $javascript->link('scriptfile'); // webroot/js/scriptfile.css` (note the helper appends the filetype)
- `echo $javascript->link('/myScripts/scriptfile'); // webroot/myScripts/scriptfile.css`